# What does "degree of informality" means here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Lawyer & Judge discussing about the law.

> Judge: Well, we don't have any serial killers in Beechum County. But
>   what we do have is every bit as sophisticated a system of justice...
>   as they do in the rest of the country.
>
> Lawyer: Oh, I'm sure.
>
> Judge: You being from New York and all might have the impression that
>   law is... practiced with a certain **degree of informality** down here. It
>   isn't?
>
> Lawyer: Right.

Does it means Bribing the lawyers to win the case, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bribing has nothing at all to do with this.

[The only reference I could find was at Wordpress:](https://informality.wordpress.com/category/definitions/)

There are dictionary definitions as well.

> **informal**
>
> noun
>   relaxed, friendly, or unofficial style or nature; absence of formality.
>   "he enjoyed the informality of the occasion"  (Google Dictionary)

The degree simply means the amount. So the simple definition is that the judge is telling the lawyer than in spite of what the lawyer may think about a rural court, the system is no less formal than the one back in NY. The law is upheld fully in both places. The lawyer inferred that the system was less precise or formal in the rural setting.